# How can I sort a map contains another map by numbers

Tags: java, sorting, collections, hashmap

I have a HashMap of type:

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>>
```

This HashMap has values like

```
{name, {dateasString, numberOfTasks}}
```

I want to sort this by `numberOfTasks`. I can't find the way to do that.

Comment: could you give a concrete example of what you want the sort result to be ?

Comment: I think you would need to create a second map of `<Integer, String>`, basically, coping the contents of the second map (`<String, Integer>`) over to it and use it as a look up into this second map.  I'd recommend using something like a `TreeMap` to make your life simpler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't sort a `HashMap`, but you can get a sorted Array (or a List) of
the keys. How you want to define your sort is up to you - just modify the
comparator (or the `numberOfTasks` function that it calls:)

So something like this?

```
public static void main() {
    final
    HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>> map = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>>();

    String[] keys = (String[]) map.keySet().toArray();

    Arrays.sort(keys, new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String k1, String k2) {
            int v1 = numberOfTasks(map.get(k1));
            int v2 = numberOfTasks(map.get(k2));
            return Integer.valueOf(v1).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(v2));
        }
    });

    // 'keys' is now sorted the way you want.

}

public static int numberOfTasks(HashMap<String, Integer> map) {
    int max = 0;
    for (Integer i : map.values()) {
        if (i > max) max = i;
    }
    return max;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create your custom `Comparator` that compares elemetns according to the sum of objects, and use `Arrays.sort()` or `Collections.sort()` after populating a list/array with the data:

```
//populate example data:
final Map<String,Map<String,Integer>> map = new HashMap<String, Map<String,Integer>>();
map.put("x", new HashMap<String, Integer>());
map.get("x").put("t1",1);
map.get("x").put("t2",1);
map.get("x").put("t3",1);
map.put("y", new HashMap<String, Integer>());
map.get("y").put("t1",2);
map.get("y").put("t2",2);
map.get("y").put("t3",2);
map.put("z", new HashMap<String, Integer>());
map.get("z").put("t1",3);
map.get("z").put("t2",3);
map.get("z").put("t3",3);

//populate the data in a list:  
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(map.keySet());

//sort the data with a custom comparator:
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String>() {
    private int getSum(String s) { 
        int sum = 0;
        for (Integer x : map.get(s).values()) {
            if (x != null) sum += x;
        }
        return sum;
    }
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        return new Integer(getSum(o1)).compareTo(new Integer(getSum(o2)));
    }
});

System.out.println(list);
```

Note, to improve performance you could use a caching mechanism to avoid recalculating the sum of each element every time it is being compared.

Answer (score 1):

Does the second `HashMap` have to be a `HashMap`? Can you convert the second `HashMap` into a class specifically for this? Perhaps something like this:

```
private class TaskList
{
    String dateAsString;
    int numTasks;
    public TaskList(String dateAsString, int numTasks)
    {
        this.dateAsString = dateAsString;
        this.numTasks = numTasks;
    }
    public getDateAsString()
    {
        return dateAsString;
    }
    public getNumTasks()
    {
        return numTasks;
    }
}
```

Then you can say `HashMap<String, TaskList>` and access the number of tasks directly and sort them accordingly. Even then I don't think `HashMap` is right for this.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there is a way to do this in the Java APIs. You will either have to do it manually by extracting the data in a separate model and sort that or redesign the model such as it will allow sorting on that field easier.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to convert the hashmap to an array.  If it were possible to sort a hashmap  it would completely defeat the purpose of using one in the first place.

```
hashMap.keySet().toArray(); // returns an array of keys
hashMap.values().toArray(); // returns an array of values

Arrays.sort(array); // sorts an array
```

Hope that helps.